# Error en consulta de sqlite con SELECT CASE

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE var(nombre VARCHAR(255),entero INT(5),texto VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TEMP TABLE param(nombre VARCHAR(255),entero INT(5),texto VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO param (nombre,texto) VALUES('criterio','');
INSERT INTO param (nombre,entero) VALUES('pagina',1);
INSERT INTO param (nombre,entero) VALUES('numRegistros',10);
INSERT INTO var (nombre,entero) VALUES('indiceinicial',( (SELECT entero FROM param WHERE nombre='pagina') - 1 ) * (SELECT entero FROM param WHERE nombre='numRegistros'));
SELECT CASE (SELECT texto FROM param WHERE nombre='criterio') 
    WHEN '' THEN (SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT (SELECT entero FROM param WHERE nombre='numRegistros') OFFSET (SELECT entero FROM var WHERE nombre='indiceinicial'))
    ELSE
        (SELECT * FROM clientes
        WHERE id LIKE '%'||(SELECT texto FROM param WHERE nombre='criterio')||'%'
        OR nombre LIKE '%'||(SELECT texto FROM param WHERE nombre='criterio')||'%'
        OR fecha_inicio = (SELECT texto FROM param WHERE nombre='criterio')
        OR fecha_final = (SELECT texto FROM param WHERE nombre='criterio')
        OR dni LIKE '%'||(SELECT texto FROM param WHERE nombre='criterio')||'%'
        ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT (SELECT entero FROM param WHERE nombre='numRegistros') OFFSET (SELECT entero FROM var WHERE nombre='indiceinicial'))
    END;
DROP TABLE var;
DROP TABLE param;
```

La consulta me devuelve el siguiente error

> [10:04:02] Error while executing SQL query on database 'spartan': only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Las tablas `var` Y `param` simulan ser una variable y los parámetros de una funcion en MySQL, si ejecuto cada uno de los subqueries si me bota un único resultado, el problema esta cuando lo ejecuto todo en bloque.

Answer (score 0):

El `SELECT * FROM clientes` dentro de un `CASE` está devolviendo más de un valor (varios campos, todos los que tiene la tabla clientes). Por eso da ese error.

Para solucionarlo el CASE podría devolverte solo el `id` de los clientes que te interesan para luego hacer un `JOIN` de ese valor con `clientes` para obtener el resto de los campos.

Puse en https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nhM62kEDNyQpBZ2UoGx51Z/0 lo que usé para probar.

Tarde pero quizás pueda ayudarte la idea o la página db-fiddle